# XSD Configuration to Reference Attributes Configured in XML file at Runtime

Tags: java, xml, xsd

**Question**: Is there a way (with something like `tns:`) to set up the `.xsd` configuration for an XML file to reference a list of attributes that are configured in XML File at runtime?

This is my situation:

I have an `.xsd` schema file, `Labels.xsd` for an xml file `Labels.xml`.

`Labels.xsd` contains the following:

```
<complexType name="LabelList">
    <sequence>
        <element name="label" type="tns:MyLabel" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            minOccurs="1"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="MyLabel">
    <attribute name="labelName" type="token" use="required"/>
    <!-- There are other attributes and sequences in MyLabel -->
</complexType>
```

Users can add to the `Labels.xml` file and add their own custom labels and change the names while my java application runs. The changes are picked up at run time.

I have another file, `MyMainTable.xml` that uses the schema from `Tables.xsd`. This file creates a table using the labels from the `Labels.xml` file above. The schema is in a different schema file than the schema for the `Labels.xml` file.

The `Tables.xml` file contains the following:

```
<complexType name="MyMainTable">
    <sequence>
        <element name="table" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="tableElement" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <complexType>
                            <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required">
                                <annotation>
                                    <documentation>
                                    This should be one of the types of 
                                    MyLabel.label.labelName that are configured in the 
                                    LabelList sequence
                                    Users can change the names of and add to the 
                                    types in MyLabel.labelName xml file.
                                    </documentation>
                                </annotation>
                            </attribute>
                        </complexType>
                    </element>
                </sequence>
                <!-- There are other attributes in this type, but they are not relevant -->
             </complexType>
         </element>
     </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Example of the `Labels.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Labels xmlns="<my schema locaiton>">

<FavoriteLabels>
   <label labelName="LabelA">
     <!-- other attributes such as color -->
   </label>
   <label labelName="LabelB">
     <!-- other attributes such as color -->
   </label>
   <label labelName="LabelC">
     <!-- other attributes such as color -->
   </label>
</FavoriteLabels>

<OtherLabels>
   <label labelName="OtherA">
     <!-- other attributes such as color -->
   </label>
   <label labelName="OtherB">
     <!-- other attributes such as color -->
   </label>
   <label labelName="OtherC">
     <!-- other attributes such as color -->
   </label>
</OtherLabels>
</Labels>
```

The name in the tableElement can be in the FavoriteLabels list or the OtherLabels list

Currently I do the check in my Java code when the table is built, but I would like the check to be done when the XML file is parsed. Similar to how a check is down for an `Enum` configured in an `.xsd` file.

Is there a way in the `.xsd` configuration to ensure the `name` attribute of the `tableElement` is contained in the list of the labels the user has configured at runtime in the `Labels.xml` file?

Comment: Can you show a short example of a Labels.xml file?

Comment: @helderdarocha I added an example. This all isn't cut and paste exactly from my code because there are other details that make the code a little more complex that aren't relevant to the problem, but the xml file is basically copy and pasted from my xml file just with names changed and some items commented out.

Comment: That seems like a problem which could be solved with key/keyref. Did you try using it? I have an example with that, and I can try to adapt your problem to it.

Comment: I had not even heard of that (xml is not my strong suit to be honest). Any example would be great and I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted your example below. It might capture the problem which you are trying to solve or at least show you a possible strategy.

Here is a XML file with both labels and tables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://my-namespace my-schema.xsd"
      xmlns="http://my-namespace">
    <labels>
        <label label="LabelA"/>
        <label label="LabelB"/>
        <label label="LabelC"/>
    </labels>
    <tables>
        <table name="LabelB"/> 
        <table name="LabelB"/>
        <table name="LabelA"/> 
        <table name="LabelC"/>
    </tables>
</root>
```

You can probably use separate files (I wasn't able to do it using only XML Schema because the key/keyref association uses XPath; but it might be possible, or you can merge the files in memory before processing them).

In the schema, I defined a key/keyref pair associating the labels to the tables. The associations are made using XPath in the context of the element where they are defined. I used ID and IDREF as token types because they are stricter and guarantee uniqueness in the whole document.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:tns="http://my-namespace" targetNamespace="http://my-namespace">

    <xs:complexType name="LabelList">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="label" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="TableList">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="table" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:IDREF" use="required"/>                   
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="labels" type="tns:LabelList"/>
                <xs:element name="tables" type="tns:TableList"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <!-- These are the keys and references; they are in the current element's context -->
        <xs:key name="LabelsKey">
            <xs:selector xpath="labels/label"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@label"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="TablesRef" refer="tns:LabelsKey">
            <xs:selector xpath="tables/table"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
        </xs:keyref>

    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now if you add a table of a label which is not defined on the list, such as:

```
<table name="LabelZ"/>
```

You will get a validation error.

Comment: You can read more about key/keyref here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-key

Comment: +1 Because this is definitely a good strategy for a similar situation. Unfortunately because of the way our schemas are set (templates in different xsd files) this won't work. But it sounds like the way our schema is set up there is no way to do the validating in the xml files. It might be java validation only. If that is true I'll accept this as an answer because you mentioned having to merge the files.